Nginx - Header directives priority within blocks
Does someone knows the priority rules that applies to header directives (like Expires) when used in different nested blocks, like a [server](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) section, and a [location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) inside?
The documentation about How nginx processes a request and others have no responses for this.
Example configuration:
server {
    expires 1d;
    location /c {
        expires 2d;
    }
}

The goal is to have a default rule (1 day) and for the requests matching the specific location /c modify it to 2d.
Of course expires header can be used in another location block, but as actual configurations are much larger and complex, the ideal solution is to have this "default" configuration, and then specific overwrites when needed.

The configuration in your question matches your goal. The expires in the server block is inherited by all location blocks, except where it's explicitly specified.

Thanks @RichardSmith for your response. For some odd reason, I didn't see it before. Now it properly shows the ''Cache-Control: max-age=172800'' response header.
